# Windows 10 VPN host does not accept connections

Tags: networking, windows-10, router, vpn, ports

I've been trying to setup the VPN hosting in Windows 10 Pro.

On the **VPN host**

- setup New Incoming Connection
- added dedicated user for connection
- specified acceptable IP range
- allow clients to assign IP
- opened port 1723 in the Windows firewall
- forwarded port 1723 on the router

On the **VPN client**

- setup a new VPN client connection with PPTP + encryption + MSCHAP
- dialed into connection with new user credentials

I keep getting *The network connection between your computer and the vpn server...*

A port scan from a Linux machine on the client end reveals the port is somehow closed:

```
$ nmap -Pn [vpn-host] -p 1723
PORT     STATE  SERVICE
1723/tcp closed pptp
```

This used to work when the host machine was running Windows 7.  Is this yet another Windows 10 "quirk" with some obscure workaround required?

Comment: Sigh... VPN host just needed a reboot.  Windows...